# why the background image only shows in live preview in brackets

Tags: html, css, adobe-brackets

I assigned a background image to a section using css and the image only shows up in live preview in brackets. Is this supposed to happen or I did something wrong. Here's The Code:

```
background: url(/img/background.jpeg) center center no-repeat fixed;
background-size: cover;
```

Comment: And where does it not show? Is the path correct?

Comment: yes the path is correct. when I open the index.html like a file://... it doesn't show the background image. I have to use brackets's live preview feature for the background to show up

Comment: Being able to open the file via `file:///` doesn't mean that your browser can access the file via `http://`

Answer (score 1):

I changed the path to:

```
background: url(../img/background.jpeg) center center no-repeat fixed;
background-size: cover;
```

putting the two dots worked for me!!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try something like this-

```
img {
border: 1px solid #ddd;
border-radius: 4px;
padding: 5px;}
<img src="example.jpg" alt="example">
```

Or this-

```
body {border-style: groove;border-width: 3px; border-color: Black;
         width:1300px; padding: 25px; background-color: Aqua;
     background-image: url("NSIC-logo1.png");
         background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position:50% 10% }
```